# Why is Numpy.gradient returning a list instead of ndarray ?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, gradient

I have a numpy.ndarray of 3D and I need to calculate its gradient and obtain a new ndarray with the same dimensions. I'm using numpy.gradient to do so but it is returning a list instead. How can I get np.gradient to return a np.ndarray?

```
    force = np.gradient(phi)*(-1)
```

Where phi is my 300³ matrix and I keep obtaining

```
    print(type(force))
    type : <class 'list'>
```

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't produce the output you've shown; `gradient` should return an array, and `print(type(force))` shouldn't produce output in that format. Can you strip your code down to [the bare minimum that still contains the buggy part and still demonstrates the bug when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then post that?

Comment: give us `phi` so we can replicate your result.  this is weird, because the docstring for `gradient` says it should return a list.  have you checked whether `np.gradient(phi)` -- i.e., sans the `*(-1)` -- is a list?

Answer (score 1):

The docs say `gradient` returns a (list of) `N arrays of the same shape as`f`giving the derivative of`f`with
  respect to each dimension.`

An example in `np.gradient` returns a list - a list of 2 arrays

```
In [105]: np.gradient(np.array([[1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=np.float))
Out[105]: 
[array([[ 2.,  2., -1.],
       [ 2.,  2., -1.]]),
 array([[-0.5,  2.5,  5.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]])]
```

A 1d input produces an array

```
In [106]: np.gradient(np.array([1, 2, 6], dtype=np.float))
Out[106]: array([-0.5,  2.5,  5.5])
```

A 3d array gives me a list of 3 arrays:

```
In [110]: len(np.gradient(np.ones((30,30,30))))
Out[110]: 3
```